# Save pre-formatted column-view lists to .txt file - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

thanks for helping.

This python code format my lists into column-view style:

```
for ele1,ele2,ele3 in zip(I,a,F):
   print('{:<10}{:<10}{:<}'.format(ele1,ele2,ele3))
```

where I,a,F are previously done lists of the same size. The question is: How do I save this result into a .txt file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
with open('file_name.txt', 'w') as filename:
    for ele1,ele2,ele3 in zip(I,a,F):
        print('{:<10}{:<10}{:<}'.format(ele1,ele2,ele3), file=filename)
```

Comment: You saved my life Sir. Thank you so much!